# allow websites to prompt for information using scripted windows

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I think I've used FF so long now and NOT IE that I've become dumb to IE 7 and 8.

So this is a very late question and I'm sure everyone knows by now but **"allow websites to prompt for information using scripted windows"**...did this replace the allow javascript in the Advanced tab?

Holy sh**, I can't believe it, but I haven't used IE in like 2 years as a developer other than to test the site I am building but never had to enable this in the custom security for my javascript windows to pop....so why did I have to do this now...the site I am trying to use is a cold fusion site, does that make any difference?  I am not coding in cold fusion but one of our legacy apps is made in cold fusion and throws javascript windows up.

Comment: Interesting, why the -2 people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came in with IE 7, it seems (search for window.prompt in the [IE 7 release notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa740486.aspx)).

So, this is an IE & JavaScript thing, not ColdFusion-specific.

Them’s the breaks.

Comment: looks to me like a bad usability issue.  I've never seen anyone prompt like this in a JS window to add information to a textbox.

Comment: I’ve never seen a site that used window.prompt, to be honest. A move like this from Microsoft does effectively kill that particular language feature; as you say, it’s not great for the user if they get a security warning just because you asked them to type something in.